# Common "tick" in online multiplayer games how to?

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, multiplayer

Here is a situation. Let's say I'm building an **online 2 player game** for browsers and one of the goals is to **spawn something (an object)** for both players **on the same spot** on the screen and make it go in a linear trajectory with **same speed**. Would it be best to implement "**server tick"** which moves the object (or objects) **or** to make that a **job for a browser**. I understand the bad implications of leaving it to the browser but I also fear for a big load on the server or something. Any ideas on how that is generally implemeted?

Comment: You can't have the clients coordinating this if you expect that all the clients will see the same thing. Different connection speeds and loading times will throw it off. Giving the client responsibility like this can also be dangerous as information the client has can be easily manipulated by them. Give the clients copies of data from the server so they can't hack the values.

Comment: Thanks, that was my original idea, but does the solution of ticking every client from server scale well with growing number of clients?
EDIT: technology is web sockets using nodejs

Comment: I haven't written any server/client games that were anything beyond simple toys, so I can't answer that. A general rule though is to be very distrustful of any data that the client gives you and has the ability to change. Say you have the clients update the trajectory every few ms. Anyone with any coding knowledge will be able to open the developer tools, find the update function, and change it to do whatever they want. If they stop the object from moving, can you trust any data they then give you regarding their interaction with the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, there are three ways to achieve that:

- Pure Server-side Mode
- Pure Client-side Mode
- Hybrid Mode

Let's see a few details on each of them.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Applying this to your case in the three different modes would mean:

- In pure server-side mode, you send the coordinates of the trajectory in real time to both the browsers. Each browser simply receives the coordinates and displays the object at the received position. You can see a live example of this approach. Go to http://push.lightstreamer.com/ with two different browsers and move around the character in the right-bottom demo. All the movements of the characters and of the ball are decided, coordinate by coordinate, by the server and broadcast in real time to all the clients.
- In pure client-side mode, you would share an initial world state, then each browser would calculate its own evolution of the world, with possibile divergence.
- In hybrid mode, the browsers do their own calculations, as in pure client-side mode, but they periodically sync through a low frequency server-side broadcast. So, the physics run on both the server side and client side.

The easiest solution is pure-server side mode, which is perfect in not-too-complex scenarios. To make it scalable and tolerant to network delays, you need a specific server, like that used in these demos [full disclosure: I'm involved with such server]

To get more details, you can have a look at some resources I prepared in the past:

- An article: [Optimizing Multiplayer 3D Game Synchronization Over the Web](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/10/optimizing-multiplayer-3d-game.html)
- A talk at HTML5DevConf (which includes the slides I shared above): [More Than Just WebSockets for Real-Time Multiplayer Games and Collaboration](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/12/html5devconf-more-than-just-websockets.html)